# IntelliJ can't find installed packages

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I've just installed IntelliJ and imported a Maven / Spring Boot project.  I've set up my run configuration as "application", but when I try to run it, it fails and complains of not being able to resolve dependencies.  When I check my local Maven repository, those dependencies are installed:

```
/Users/user/Projects/myapplication/src/test/java/com/something
/SomethingServiceTest.java:23:29
java: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
```

local maven repo:

```
$ ll ~/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  6 user  Users   192B 21 Aug  2020 ./
drwxr-xr-x  6 user  Users   192B  2 Sep  2020 ../
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  Users    96B 21 Aug  2020 junit-jupiter/
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  Users    96B 21 Aug  2020 junit-jupiter-api/
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  Users    96B 21 Aug  2020 junit-jupiter-engine/
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  Users    96B 21 Aug  2020 junit-jupiter-params/
```

Comment: Can you build the project with Maven outside IntelliJ?

Comment: yes I can - in fact, I can do a Maven build inside IntelliJ, and I can run the project as a Jar application, but I can't run it as an appllication

Comment: Right click on the pom.xml and Maven -> Reload Project

Comment: That's it, that did it.  If this was an answer, I'd mark it as correct.  I NEVER would have figure that out so thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help! I add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ and the pom.xml are probably not in-sync.

Right click on the pom.xml and Maven -> Reload Project

Answer (score -1):

I've been the same problems. Sometimes I try to remove or change the name of the ~/.m2/repository directory.
After that, I make

> mvn clean compile and install

Try this.

Comment: He can build the project with Maven it's a IntelliJ problem